# Using python to make an auto clicker

Tags: python, python-3.x, click, mouseevent

I want to make an auto clicker using python.
Here is a kind of idea of what I have going.
I would like it so when I click it'll click 10 times.

```
import mouse

def clicker():
    if mouse.if_click('left'):
        mouse.click('left')
        mouse.click('left')
        mouse.click('left')
        mouse.click('left')
        mouse.click('left')
        mouse.click('left')

clicker()
```

Any ideas????
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `pyautogui` or `pynput` module. Both have to be installed using `pip install`. 
pyautogui example:

```
import pyautogui
for _ in range(10):
#repeat 10 times
    pyautogui.click()
```

pynput example:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()
# Press and release
mouse.press(Button.left)
mouse.release(Button.left)

# Double click; this is different from pressing and releasing
# twice on Mac OSX
mouse.click(Button.left, 2)
```

Both examples are taken from their docs and may have been modified:

pyautogui: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks 
pynput: https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/mouse.html

Answer (score 0):

First install pyautogui using pip

`pip install pyautogui`

Code:-

```
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(2)
x = 0
times = 20 # Change this to the number of times you want it to click

while True:
    if x == times:
        print("Stopped Clicking")
        break

    else:
        pyautogui.leftClick()
        x += 1
```

This code left clicks the number of times set in the variable `times` (Here, it is 20 times)

Comment: Why the `while` loop? Can't you just write `for x in range(times): pyautogui.leftClick()`?

Comment: you could also use ```for _ in range(times)``` as you don't need to keep track of the variable x.